# How to render large size pdf document in android webview?

Tags: android

In my app I am displaying a pdf document that is located in server. I am able to display a sample pdf of small size. But my pdf document size is 25mb. When I tried to display my pdf it is displaying error message saying that the file is too large. How can I display larger size pdf doc in android?

Any suggestion in this regard will be thankful.

My code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.addView(webView.getZoomControls());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.stluciadance.com/prospectus_file/sample.pdf");
webUrl="http://www.stluciadance.com/prospectus_file/mydoc.pdf";
webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ webUrl);
```

[image]

Comment: this thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39866468/8192914