# How to load large pdf file in Android into my webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

i am unable to load a large pdf file (having 900 page) into my
   webview in my android app, i try this code and working well on any
   other pdf, but when  i try to open a large one it display: No Preview
   Available.

```
        wvReport.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvReport.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wvReport.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

    wvReport.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Toast.makeText(ReportsViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

    wvReport.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {

        }
    });
    wvReport.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/viewer?url="+url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```java
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and it's working, so if the pdf is too large , will be downloaded and opened via pdf viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Webviews display html.  The fact that this works at all is by a hack-  google will convert simple pdfs into html.  It doesn't seem like they support anything that big.  Even if they did, I would expect loading a 900 page pdf converted to html would be so large I highly doubt you'd be able to load it without going OOM.  Use an apropriate pdf library, make a real pdf rendering view, and make sure not to render more of the pdf at a time than you need (or else you'll go OOM anyway).  In other words, don't rely on hacky solutions you never should have relied on in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should try alternatives like [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) running locally in your device, instead of a service like Google Docs preview.

Put it in your assets folder and tweak the example:

```
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/viewer.html");
```

Also, as @gabe-sechan mentions, you can have Out Of Memory situations. An alternative to try is a native viewer like [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer).

Comment: Do AndroidPdfViewer prevents OOM while opening large PDF file? Please reply.

Comment: I don't have experience with it in this kind of situation. It should do a much better job than PDF.js in this case, but I cannot say if OOM will never happen.